SDRAM Clock routing. Top Layer vs Sandwiched between GND/Power Planes. What's is better for EMC?
Planning a new design, were I finally removing a termination resistor on SDRAM_CLK line. Planning to increase the clock speed to 200MHz as well. Previously it looked like a straight forward decision to keep this trace on the Top layer and just enclose it in a ground pour on the Top layer and reference it to solid GND plane one L2.
Stackup:

Question what is better for EMC?

Route SDRAM_CLK line on the Top layer
Bury SDRAM_CLK to L4. Between GND planes on L2 and L5. L3 doesn't have a plane under SDRAM_CLK,it has other SDRAM lines routed. SDRAM_CLK will have to be routed on the Top layer for a portion under the MCU as, most likely, there's no possibility to place a transfer GND via close to clock pad in that area, so the clock will still be routed on Top layer for a couple of mms. The via is a regular TH via (not blind).

